# Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-34-generic but /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kernel

I have Dell laptop with processor Intel core i5-3337 processor. i installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS on it and found that my kernel version is different and /lib/modules/4.2.0-27-generic/ is different which cause me problem to install wifi driver.

My network controller is as below.

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
Memory at c0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
```

System Information

```
uname -a
Linux rabikernel 4.4.0-34-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 27 16:06:39 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


ls /lib/modules
4.2.0-27-generic
```

there is some mismatch while installing wifi driver as below

```
 sudo modprobe iwlwifi
 modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/modules.dep.bin'
 modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/modules.dep.bin'
 modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/modules.dep.bin'
 modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
 modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Function not implemented
```

so is this a bug or do i have to do some to make enable to access wireless functionality

Comment: What kernel packages do you have? `dpkg -l | grep linux`